# Sympy is not doing the substitution of a symbol with a value when it has a specified assumption

Tags: python, sympy, substitution, symbolic-math

I'm using the subs method to replace certain parameters in an expression with values prior to solving the equation.

The following simple example works fine:

```
from sympy import Symbol

Q = Symbol("Q")
exp1 = Q + 1
print(exp1.subs({'Q': 1}))  # prints 2
```

However, if the symbol has an assumption such as `real` or `positive` specified this does not work:

```
Q = Symbol("Q", positive=True)
exp1 = Q + 1
print(exp1.subs({'Q': 1}))  # prints Q + 1
```

Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a string key.

```py
print(exp1.subs({Q: 1}))
```

Comment: Oh right! Any idea why it worked in the first case?

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/assumptions.html#gotcha-symbols-with-different-assumptions

Comment: Symbols match according to name *and* assumptions. There are minimal assumptions used when creating from a string or `Symbol('x')`.